# Update statement to update multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have a question regarding the following syntax.  Is there a cleaner way to roll this up into one statement rather than two.  I've tried several iterations but this seems to be the only way I can successfully execute these two statements.

```
UPDATE employee
SET hire_date = '1979-03-15'
WHERE emp_id = 'PMA42628M' 

UPDATE employee
SET hire_date = '1988-12-22'
where emp_id = 'PSA89086M';
```

I tried this as well and I also tried using an AND statement.  Neither worked. Basically I am looking for a less newbie way then the method above, if one exists.  I spent a long time searching and did not find one.

```
UPDATE employee
SET hire_date = ('1979-03-15', '1988-12-22')
WHERE emp_id = ('PMA42628M', 'PSA89086M');
```

Appriciate any advice on this one, and by the way, I am using sql server.
Thanks

Answer (score 51):

Try this one, this will combine multiple selects and returns them as if they come from the DB:

```
UPDATE e
SET hire_date = t.hire_date
FROM dbo.employee e
JOIN (
    SELECT emp_id = 'PMA42628M', hire_date = '1979-03-15'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT emp_id = 'PSA89086M', hire_date = '1988-12-22'
) t ON t.emp_id = e.emp_id
```

If you are using SQL Server 2008 or later version, you could also use a different syntax for the derived table:

```
UPDATE e
SET hire_date = t.hire_date
FROM dbo.employee e
JOIN (
    VALUES
        ('PMA42628M', '1979-03-15'),
        ('PSA89086M', '1988-12-22')
) t (emp_id, hire_date) ON t.emp_id = e.emp_id
```

Comment: isn't the keyword `AS` missing twice?

Comment: I don't use `AS` keyword in this situation, because it's unnecessary.

Comment: The keyword `AS` is not required, but encouraged for better readability.

Comment: @TT, this is a personal preference. :)

Comment: @TT.: ...but may be discouraged by those who switch between Oracle and non-Oracle often. (Oracle doesn't support `AS` before table alias declarations: [this works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/12053), [this doesn't](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/12054).)

Comment: @AndriyM Thanks for the heads up. I just wish that relational DB vendors would implement more of the standard...

Comment: what doe the `dbo` do in the FROM clause?

Comment: @NathanHinchey nothing. dbo is just the default schema of a database and since OP didn't give an own schema I guess Devart just assumed that the table is located on the default schema.

Comment: it worked! Thank you! I never came across using FROM clause with UPDATE one!

Comment: I prefer this solution!!

Answer (score 15):

> I am looking for a less newbie way

Doing two separate update statements is (according to me) "the less newbie way" you could complicate stuff and do something like this.

```
update employee
set hire_date = case emp_id
                  when 'PMA42628M' then '1979-03-15'
                  when 'PSA89086M' then '1988-12-22'
                end
where emp_id in ('PMA42628M', 'PSA89086M')
```

but what would that gain you? The entire update would run in one implicit transaction so if you want your two updates to be in a transaction you just use `begin transaction .... commit`.

Comment: I ended up on this question because I was googling for a way to optimize a slow (interactive) application that does about 100K update statements over the course of a minute. Switching to a combined variant like suggested gave us about 700% speedup so we now do the same work in less than ten seconds. Putting it all in a transcation doesn't help because it's the dispatch and roundtrip time for all the SQL statements that takes up the majority of the time.

Comment: In my query my `WHERE id IN (...)` is gnarly, so this is a much neater way than two `UPDATE`s.

Answer (score 12):

You can make a temporary table or a table variable containing the updates you want to do, then run the `UPDATE` statement linking the table to the table you intend to update.

Note that for two updates, you get two statements: the `INSERT` into the update table and the `UPDATE` statement itself. The number of statements remains two though for as many updates you need to do.

```
CREATE TABLE #employee (emp_id VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,hire_date DATE NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO #employee (emp_id,hire_date)
VALUES ('PMA42628M','2013-06-05'),('PSA89086M','2013-06-05');

CREATE TABLE #target_updates(emp_id VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,hire_date DATE NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO #target_updates (emp_id,hire_date)
VALUES ('PMA42628M','1979-03-15'),('PSA89086M','1988-12-22');
```

```
UPDATE
    #employee
SET
    hire_date=tu.hire_date
FROM
    #employee AS e
    INNER JOIN #target_updates AS tu ON
        tu.emp_id=e.emp_id;

SELECT
    *
FROM
    #employee
ORDER BY
    emp_id;
```

```
DROP TABLE #target_updates;
DROP TABLE #employee;
```

Comment: This shd be the accepted answer as its applicable to updating n number of rows from a table that already exists as well

Answer (score -2):

update table_name set='value'  where orgid in (idnum1, idnum2)