# pymssql UPDATE statement with temp table

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I'm using pymssql and Python 3.6 to update multiple rows with one query on a SQL Server 2019 database.

I use the following query (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16932591/1046299) :

```
UPDATE e
SET hire_date = t.hire_date
FROM dbo.employee e
JOIN (
    VALUES
        ('PMA42628M', '1979-03-15'),
        ('PSA89086M', '1988-12-22')
) t (emp_id, hire_date) ON t.emp_id = e.emp_id
```

However, when I run `db_cur.execute(sql_query)` then `db_conn.commit()` the table is not updated. When I run the query in SQL Server, all is good.

Comment: Please show Python implementation of query. Are you passing parameters?

Comment: There's nothing more than that. No parameters. The sql_query variable stores the query that I try to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution on this post: [pymssql ( python module ) unable to use temporary tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796783/pymssql-python-module-unable-to-use-temporary-tables)

I upgraded my version of pymssql and it worked.